# login page not working in WordPress but not displaying any error message

Tags: php, wordpress

login page not working in worpress but not displaying any error message,

login page not working in wordpress,
username and password is mismatch means i got error message,
username and password is correct means redirect to same page(same login page),
Cannot move to login page,
how to rectify this error.

Comment: cannot move wp-login.php to home page

Comment: Anything in your PHP logs?  Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: yes, am clear browser cache and cookie also but displaying same problem.

Comment: Anything in your PHP logs?

Comment: Any errors in your javascript console?  Does it still happen on a different browser / computer?  Have you changed anything recently (like the site URL or the WordPress URL)?

Comment: no errors comming in javascritpt and php...

Comment: errors nothing but this same code run in different system...

Comment: So you've migrated your code base to a new server?  Did you follow the instructions in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)?  Does removing (or renaming, so you have a copy) your `.htaccess` file help?

Comment: yes, am delete all copied files, newly download and run but cannot run same problem is displaying.

Comment: If it's a new WordPress download, I'm not sure what's going on.  If it's a new download of the files from the "different system", make sure you follow the procedure in the Codex I linked to above.  You need to update the contents of your database correctly for it to work.  A straight database update won't do the trick with PHP-serialized data.